# SpringBoot+JPA+Hibernate relationship mapping

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data

I have a situation where i have to register user and the information stores in multiple tables.

**table structure:**

```
Users table
```

[image: Users Table]

```
UserProfiles Table
```

[image: UserProfiles Table]

```
Configurations Table
```

[image: Configurations Table]

```
Address table
```

[image: Addresses Table]

As, above snap shows my table structure, i want to map all these table into springboot with hibernate and JPA. I really don't know how maintain relationship between these table.

```
**Explanation**
```

1. One user map to one profile only.
2. One profile can contain many address
3. Address country,state and city map to configurations table configid like country = configid, state = configid, city = configid.
4. Configurations table is the base table for address and users table is the base table for userprofiles and userprofile is the base table for addresses.

Please suggest me the solution. If any further clearification required please let me know.

**Update #1**

User.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
@PasswordMatches
public class User  {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "user_id")
    private long userId;

    @NotNull
    @NotEmpty
    @Size(min=5)
    @Column(name = "username")
    private String userName;

    @NotNull
    @NotEmpty
    @ValidEmail
    @Size(min=5)
    private String email;

    @NotNull
    @NotEmpty
    @Size(min=6, max=20)
    private String password;

    @NotNull
    @NotEmpty
    @Size(min=8, max=20)
    private transient String cpassword;
  .... // getter & setters and default constructor
}
```

UserProfile.java

```
public class UserProfile {


    @NotNull
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long userProfileId;

    @OneToOne
    private User user;

    @NotNull
    @NotEmpty
    private String firstName;

    @NotNull
    @NotEmpty
    private String lastName;

    @NotNull
    @NotEmpty
    private String gender;

    @NotNull
    @NotEmpty
    private String phoneNumber;

 .... // getter & setter and default constructor.
}
```

Address.java

```
public class Address {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long addressId;

    @NotNull
    @NotEmpty
    @Size(min=5)
    private String address;

    @NotNull
    @NotEmpty
    @OneToOne
    private Configuration country;

    @NotNull
    @NotEmpty
    @OneToOne
    private Configuration state;

    @NotNull
    @NotEmpty
    @OneToOne
    private Configuration city;

    @NotNull
    @NotEmpty
    @Size(min=6, max=6)
    private int pincode;

    @ManyToOne
    private UserProfile userProfile;
    ... // getters & setter and default method
}
```

Configuration.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "configurations")
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
public class Configuration {

    @Id
    @Column(name="configid")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long configId;

    @NotNull
    @NotEmpty
    @Size(min=3)
    @Column(name="configname")
    private String configName;

    @NotNull
    @NotEmpty
    @Size(min=3)
    @Column(name="configtype")
    private String configType;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="parentid")
    private Configuration parentid;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="parentid")
    public List<Configuration> childConfigs = new ArrayList<Configuration>();

    @CreatedDate
    @Column(name = "created_at")
    private long createdDate;

    @Column(name = "created_by")
    @CreatedBy
    private String createdBy;

    @LastModifiedDate
    @Column(name = "updated_at")
    private long modifiedDate;

    @Column(name = "updated_by")
    @LastModifiedBy
    private String modifiedBy;
   .... //getters & setters and default constructor
}
```

register.html

```
<form action="#" th:action="@{'/signup/create'}"
                                th:object="${user}" method="post" autocomplete="off">
                                <fieldset>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label th:text="#{register.label.username}"
                                            class="control-label col-md-4" />
                                        <div class="col-md-6">
                                            <input type="text" th:field="*{userName}"
                                                class="form-control" /> <span class="help-block"> <strong
                                                th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('userName')}"
                                                th:errors="*{userName}">User Name Error</strong></span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label th:text="#{register.label.firstname}"
                                            class="control-label col-md-4" />
                                        <div class="col-md-6">
                                            <input type="text" th:field="*{firstName}"
                                                class="form-control" /> <span class="help-block"> <strong
                                                th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('firstName')}"
                                                th:errors="*{firstName}">First Name Error</strong></span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label th:text="#{register.label.lastname}"
                                            class="control-label col-md-4" />
                                        <div class="col-md-6">
                                            <input type="text" th:field="*{lastName}"
                                                class="form-control" /> <span class="help-block"> <strong
                                                th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('lastName')}"
                                                th:errors="*{lastName}">Last Name Error</strong></span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label th:text="#{register.label.gender}"
                                            class="control-label col-md-4" />
                                        <div class="col-md-6">
                                            <input type="text" th:field="*{gender}" class="form-control" />
                                            <span class="help-block"> <strong
                                                th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('gender')}" th:errors="*{gender}">Gender
                                                    Error</strong></span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label th:text="#{register.label.phonenumber}"
                                            class="control-label col-md-4" />
                                        <div class="col-md-6">
                                            <input type="text" th:field="*{phoneNumber}"
                                                class="form-control" /> <span class="help-block"> <strong
                                                th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('phoneNumber')}"
                                                th:errors="*{phoneNumber}">Phone Number Error</strong></span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label th:text="#{register.label.country}"
                                            class="col-md-4 control-label">Country:</label>
                                        <div class="col-md-6">
                                            <select class="form-control" th:field="*{country}">
                                                <option value="-1">--- Select Country ---</option>
                                                <option th:each="country : ${countries}" th:value="${country.configid}" th:text="${coutry.configname}"></option>
                                            </select> <span class="help-block"> <strong
                                                th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('country')}"
                                                th:errors="*{country}">Country Error</strong></span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label th:text="#{register.label.state}"
                                            class="col-md-4 control-label">State:</label>
                                        <div class="col-md-6">
                                            <select class="form-control" th:field="*{state}">
                                                <option value="-1">--- Select State ---</option>
                                                <option value="2">Delhi</option>
                                                <option value="3">Utter Pradesh</option>
                                            </select> <span class="help-block"> <strong
                                                th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('state')}" th:errors="*{country}">Country
                                                    Error</strong></span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label th:text="#{register.label.city}"
                                            class="col-md-4 control-label">City:</label>
                                        <div class="col-md-6">
                                            <select class="form-control" th:field="*{city}">
                                                <option value="-1">--- Select City ---</option>
                                                <option value="4">Delhi</option>
                                                <option value="5">Kanpur</option>
                                                <option value="3">Noida</option>
                                            </select> <span class="help-block"> <strong
                                                th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('city')}" th:errors="*{country}">Country
                                                    Error</strong></span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label th:text="#{register.label.pincode}"
                                            class="control-label col-md-4">Pin Code</label>
                                        <div class="col-md-6">
                                            <input type="text" th:field="*{pincode}"
                                                class="form-control" /> <span class="help-block"> <strong
                                                th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('pincode')}"
                                                th:errors="*{pincode}">Pincode Error</strong></span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label th:text="#{register.label.address}"
                                            class="control-label col-md-4">Address:</label>
                                        <div class="col-md-6">
                                            <textarea th:field="*{address}" class="form-control"></textarea>
                                            <span class="help-block"> <strong
                                                th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('address')}"
                                                th:errors="*{address}">Address Error</strong></span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </fieldset>
                                <fieldset>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label th:text="#{login.label.email}"
                                            class="control-label col-md-4" />
                                        <div class="col-md-6">
                                            <input type="email" th:field="*{email}" class="form-control" />
                                            <span class="help-block"> <strong
                                                th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('email')}" th:errors="*{email}">Email
                                                    Error</strong></span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label th:text="#{login.label.password}"
                                            class="control-label col-md-4" />
                                        <div class="col-md-6">
                                            <input type="password" th:field="*{password}"
                                                class="form-control" /> <span class="help-block"> <strong
                                                th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('password')}"
                                                th:errors="*{password}">Password Error</strong></span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label th:text="#{login.label.cpassword}"
                                            class="control-label col-md-4" />
                                        <div class="col-md-6">
                                            <input type="password" th:field="*{cpassword}"
                                                class="form-control" /> <span class="help-block"> <strong
                                                th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('cpassword')}"
                                                th:errors="*{cpassword}">Confirm Password Error</strong></span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </fieldset>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-4">
                                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"
                                            th:utext="register.submitbtn.label">
                                            <i class="fa fa-btn fa-sign-in"></i> Register Me
                                        </button>
                                        <a class="btn btn-link" href="@{/login}"
                                            th:text="#{register.link.signin}">Registered ! Sign In</a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </form>
```

I am getting property not readable error, while try to create new user.

Please look into and suggest me the solution.
Thanks.

Comment: The gold keys are primary keys, the gray keys are foreign keys.

Comment: Yes, i have created these relationship in phpmyadmin designer. Question is how to do the same thing in JPA, Spring, and Hibernate.

Comment: Well, put together some entities and look at the SQL it makes and if you have an specific questions pls post.

Comment: Ok, let do if i face any issue i'll let you know.

Comment: @Nicholas, I am getting errors while tried create registration page. I did not understand how to go further. I am updating my question with the relevant details.